# PHP: Function() check form indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops, indexing

EDIT:
I solved my problem:
Thanks to all of you for your comment, it help me to think differently:
I didn't know that return ...; was behaving this way ( I believed it  was just sending value not ending function ), so like I said, I'm just starting, I' a newbie...
I solved my problem with multidimensional array, I think it should work like I want now. I posted the code at the end of this post.

**------------------------------------------------------------**

*I'm trying to make a basic checking form function that would be used to check all the form on my future website.It took me several hours (days...) to do this short code, because I'm a newbie in PHP, i just began few days ago.
Here is the Idea (Note that the form is way bigger I just created a smaller version of it for debugging).
PHP Library included with require() in the HTML page:*

```
function check_form() {
    $n = 0;
    $indexed = array_values($_POST);
    // How should I do to make this loop,
    // to edit the HTML of each input one by one,
    // without modifying other input that the one corresponding
    // to the $n position in the table ?
    if (isset($indexed[$n])) {
        if (!empty($indexed[$n])) {
            $value = $indexed[$n];
            $icon = define_article_style()[0];
            $color = define_article_style()[1];
        } else {
            $value = define_article_style()[4];
            $icon = define_article_style()[2];
            $color = define_article_style()[3];
        }
        $form_data_input = array($value, $icon, $color);
        return $form_data_input;
    }
}
```

*The HTML Form:*

```
        <form role="form" method="post" action="#checked">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo check_form()[1]; ?>">
                <label class="sr-only" for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control input-lg" id="title"  placeholder="Enter title * (min: 5 characters, max: 30 characters)" value="<?php echo check_form()[0]; ?>">
                <?php echo check_form()[2]; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo check_form()[1]; ?>">
                <label class="sr-only" for="another">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="another" class="form-control input-lg" id="another"  placeholder="Enter title * (min: 5 characters, max: 30 characters)" value="<?php echo check_form()[0]; ?>">
                <?php echo check_form()[2]; ?>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="check_article" value="#checked">Check</button>
        </form>
```

*My problem is that the values returned to the inputs is always the content of "title", so for example if*

```
    $array[0] = $indexed[$index];
    $array[1] = define_article_style()[0];
    $array[2] = define_article_style()[1];
```

*for "title" is equal to*

```
    $array[0] = "blabla";
    $array[1] = "myclass1";
    $array[2] = "myclass2";
```

*every other input (in this case it's just "another") of the form have the same values.
I'm a bit confused, and I don't understand very well how everything works but I think this is related to the fact that the inputs share `$array[n]`to get their values/style but I don't really understand how I can keep this concept and make it work.
So if you understand what isn't working here I would be interested about explanation (keep in mind, I'm a newbie in code, and PHP.)
Thank you.
Greetings.*

**------------------------------------------------------------**

Here is my working code ( I have to verify but I think it works correctly ).

```
function check_form() {
    $n = 0;
    $index_post = array_values($_POST);
    while ($n < count($index_post)) {
        if (isset($index_post[$n])) {
            if (!empty($index_post[$n])) {
                $value[$n] = $index_post[$n];
                $color[$n] = define_article_style()[0];
                $icon[$n] = define_article_style()[1];
            } else {
                $value[$n] = define_article_style()[4];
                $color[$n] = define_article_style()[2];
                $icon[$n] = define_article_style()[3];
            }
        }
        $array_all = [$value, $color, $icon];
        $n = $n + 1;
    }
    return $array_all;
}
```

Again, thanks for the answer, good  to see that even newbies that don't understand half of what they do when they use this function over this other function get answers here.
Thumps up.
Greetings.

Comment: There is too much confusion here i dont know where to start. array_values returns 0 based numerically indexed array, so your if statements are pointless. Next, a return statement will exit the function, so you never loop more than once

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in your code:

**First**: I supose you have a view file "form.php" and the process for the submit form in "submit_form.php", so in your html code you need to fix this (action attribute):

```
 <form role="form" method="post" action="submit_form.php">
```

**Second**: You have 2 input tags with names "title" and "another", so the $_POST array have 2 indexes:
$_POST["title"], $_POST["another"], you can check the content of this array:

```
var_dump($_POST); // this function print all the data of this array, check it.
```

Comment: First:
Actually I don't want to load an other page right now, I just want to reload the actual page and see if the correct style/value has been loaded/applied.
Second:
Yep I already use the var_dump to check the inputs, all the input are correctly registered.

The problem is that even if the value that are set in $_POST = $index are the correct from what I can see in the var_dump()
All the input take the style/value applied on the first input in the HTML.

It look like this:

http://s7.postimg.org/xk02bmdjf/before.png

http://s7.postimg.org/gxii2jkln/after.png